# boost interprocess how to remove shared memory correctly

Tags: c++, boost, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I've seen many example using this :

```
int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;

   //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
   struct shm_remove
   {
      shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   } remover;

   // do something....
}
```

The remover here will make sure that at the end of the scope, the shared memory will be removed.

Well here is my situation: I have many working processes, and I don't have a master node to coordinate things, but I want the shared memory to be closed and clean up when the last working process exist.

If I defined such remover, then the first exit worker will close the shared memory. Although, according to its document on [removing shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.removing), even if the shared memory is removed, as long as other processes are still referencing that memory, it still be still there, but just **its name is removed**, that means other processes can no longer find this memory segment. But in my case, **some worker might shut down and restart, then it won't be able to find that memory again.**

So I'm considering do nothing on it. When all process terminate, will that shared memory deleted? Or it will persist in my system somehow then lead to memory leak?

Comment: It is very suspicious that `shm_remove` constructor and destructor is exactly the same code.

Comment: @Phil1970 I've seen some boost example(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_named_interprocess) using this....I guess the idea is to clean any exist shared_memory with the name when process started, and clean it when process termianted.

Comment: The same trouble. Did you found a solution?

Comment: I'm also looking for an example of how to guarantee cleanup when last process stops using the shared memory in the absence of a "manager" process.

Comment: @Dalzhim my personal hotfix is using file lock for synchronization......the process that acquired file lock successfully will be the 'master' process and do the cleanup

Comment: @ZiqiLiu I have stored a refcount inside the shared memory in order to allow the last process to deallocate the shared memory. Although this solution suffers from the same problem as when using a master process : a crash can lead to cleanup not happening even after all processes have ended.

Comment: @Dalzhim yeah I think nothing in shared mem is crash-safe, and my application has zero-tolerance for crash corner cases.... that's why I choose file lock as a synchronization mechanism, I think it's crash-safe and guaranteed by kernel